# What is the equivalent to the Windows "Term232" program?

Tags: software-installation

What is the equivalent to the Windows "Term232" program? I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

One similar serial port terminal client with logging available for all Ubuntu distros is [minicom][1] but I am sure there are others.